# Generate self-signed certificate and create keystore and generate JWT token in Java

Tags: java, openssl, jwt, ssl-certificate, pem

I am trying to generate a jwt token from a keystore.

For this I downloaded "openssl-for-windows" https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

Run the following commands in the command prompt as an administrator.

**CLI comnd**

**Creating a sample CA certificate**

openssl.exe req -config openssl.cnf -new -x509 -keyout private.pem -out certificate.pem -days 365

**Create a kestore named keystore**

keytool –keystore keystore –genkey –alias client -keyalg rsa

**Generate certificate signing request**

keytool –keystore keystore –certreq –alias client –keyalg rsa –file client.csr

**Generate signed certificate for associated CSR**

openssl.exe x509 -req -CA certificate.pem -CAkey private.pem -in client.csr -out client.cer -days 365 -CAcreateserial

**Import CA certificate into keystore**

keytool -import -keystore keystore -file certificate.pem -alias theCARoot

**Import signed certificate for associated alias in the keystore**

keytool –import –keystore keystore –file client.cer –alias client

Next, I created a java code to generate a token.

**Main.java**

```
        public class StreamKey {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                StreamKey key = new StreamKey();
                key.getSer();

            }

            private void getSer() {

                try  {

                    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("clientkeystore");

                    char[] password = "111111".toCharArray();
                    String alias = "client";

                    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                    keyStore.load(inputStream, password);

                    Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, password);

                    LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                    Date dat = Date.from(currentTime.plusMinutes(5).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

                    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
                    claims.put("sub", alias);
                    claims.put("exp", dat.getTime());

                    String token = Jwts.builder()
                            .setHeaderParam("alg", "RS256")
                            .setHeaderParam("typ", "jwt")
                            .setClaims(claims)
                            .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.RS256).compact();

                    System.out.println(token);

                } catch (IOException | KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                         UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }


            }


        }
```

After creating the token, I went to the site https://jwt.io/ and pasted this token into the "Encoded PASTE A TOKEN HERE" field, then I opened the client.csr file in a text editor and copied the contents and pasted it into the "Public Key" field ".

After these steps, "Invalid Signature" is still highlighted in red
But if I take the content from the private.pem file and paste it into the "Private Key" field, then "Invalid Signature" is highlighted in blue.

**The question is why when I use the public key, "Invalid Signature" is highlighted in red?**

I took all the material from YouTube.

Man creates keys https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxowUHao9TI

The same person creates a jwt token using java https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWlDQaR-LLM

https://github.com/MyTestPerson/rsa-jwt

**LOG**

```
        D:\test\openssl-0.9.8k_X64>.\bin\openssl.exe req -config openssl.cnf -new -x509 -keyout private.pem -out certificate.pem -days 365
        Loading 'screen' into random state - done
        Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
        ........................++++++
        ..++++++
        writing new private key to 'private.pem'
        Enter PEM pass phrase:
        Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
        -----
        You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
        into your certificate request.
        What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
        There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
        For some fields there will be a default value,
        If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
        -----
        Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:qq
        State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:ww
        Locality Name (eg, city) []:ee
        Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:rr
        Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:tt
        Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []:yy
        Email Address []:uu

        D:\test\openssl-0.9.8k_X64>keytool -keystore keystore -genkey -alias client -keyalg rsa
        Enter keystore password:
        Re-enter new password:
        What is your first and last name?
          [Unknown]:  uu
        What is the name of your organizational unit?
          [Unknown]:  yy
        What is the name of your organization?
          [Unknown]:  tt
        What is the name of your City or Locality?
          [Unknown]:  rr
        What is the name of your State or Province?
          [Unknown]:  ee
        What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
          [Unknown]:  ww
        Is CN=uu, OU=yy, O=tt, L=rr, ST=ee, C=ww correct?
          [no]:  yes

        Generating 2 048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 90 days
                for: CN=uu, OU=yy, O=tt, L=rr, ST=ee, C=ww

        D:\test\openssl-0.9.8k_X64>keytool -keystore keystore -certreq -alias client -keyalg rsa -file client.csr
        Enter keystore password:

        D:\test\openssl-0.9.8k_X64>.\bin\openssl.exe x509 -req -CA certificate.pem -CAkey private.pem -in client.csr -out client.cer -days 365 -CAcreateserial
        Loading 'screen' into random state - done
        Signature ok
        subject=/C=ww/ST=ee/L=rr/O=tt/OU=yy/CN=uu
        Getting CA Private Key
        Enter pass phrase for private.pem:

        D:\test\openssl-0.9.8k_X64>keytool -import -keystore keystore -file certificate.pem -alias theCARoot
        Enter keystore password:
        Owner: EMAILADDRESS=uu, CN=yy, OU=tt, O=rr, L=ee, ST=ww, C=qq
        Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=uu, CN=yy, OU=tt, O=rr, L=ee, ST=ww, C=qq
        Serial number: a51a542a98afc4c9
        Valid from: Sun Aug 14 17:33:41 SAKT 2022 until: Mon Aug 14 17:33:41 SAKT 2023
        Certificate fingerprints:
                 SHA1: 45:E2:09:05:60:D6:AA:5A:21:6E:58:F3:4D:12:1E:85:14:1C:B8:7C
                 SHA256: 80:A5:C6:19:6B:F0:14:F0:9C:0F:8D:C0:80:96:AF:12:F7:6A:E3:25:F0:81:55:ED:32:52:BD:71:2D:5E:E9:38
        Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA (weak)
        Subject Public Key Algorithm: 1024-bit RSA key (weak)
        Version: 3

        Extensions:

        #1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 04 BA 9F 89 CE E3 9C 37   C8 0B 36 86 68 55 BD 5D  .......7..6.hU.]
        0010: CA 17 80 22                                        ..."
        ]
        [EMAILADDRESS=uu, CN=yy, OU=tt, O=rr, L=ee, ST=ww, C=qq]
        SerialNumber: [    a51a542a 98afc4c9]
        ]

        #2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen: no limit
        ]

        #3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 04 BA 9F 89 CE E3 9C 37   C8 0B 36 86 68 55 BD 5D  .......7..6.hU.]
        0010: CA 17 80 22                                        ..."
        ]
        ]


        Warning:
        The input uses the SHA1withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.
        The input uses a 1024-bit RSA key which is considered a security risk. This key size will be disabled in a future update.

        Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
        Certificate was added to keystore

        D:\test\openssl-0.9.8k_X64>keytool -import -keystore keystore -file client.cer -alias client
        Enter keystore password:
        Certificate reply was installed in keystore

        Warning:
        Issuer <thecaroot> uses a 1024-bit RSA key which is considered a security risk. This key size will be disabled in a future update.
        The input uses the SHA1withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.

        D:\test\openssl-0.9.8k_X64>
```